driver.find_element can't find an element by "class_name"
I tried to use driver.find_element, by "class_name" to  find button and click on it for expanding rooms on  -
https://www.qantas.com/hotels/properties/18482?adults=2&checkIn=2024-04-16&checkOut=2024-04-17&children=0&infants=0#view-rooms

, but received error message
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".css-v84xw-NakedButton eml2css7"}
  (Session info: chrome=123.0.6312.106); For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors#no-such-element-exception

HTML code with button -
<button data-testid="expand-offer-summary" aria-label="Expand offer details" type="button" class="css-v84xw-NakedButton eml2css7"><svg class="en7chz91 css-1osu69f-StyledSvg-Icon en7chz90" viewBox="0 0 24 24" title="expandMore" fill="currentcolor"><path d="M16.59 8.59L12 13.17 7.41 8.59 6 10l6 6 6-6z"></path></svg></button>

Python code(I tried with explycity wait as wll -
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
def rooms():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get("https://www.qantas.com/hotels/properties/18482?adults=2&checkIn=2024-04-16&checkOut=2024-04-17&children=0&infants=0#view-rooms")
    driver.implicitly_wait(5)
    content = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content,'html.parser')
    Button = driver.find_element('class name',"css-v84xw-NakedButton eml2css7")
    Button.click()
    
rooms()


Try driver.find_element_by_class_name("css-v84xw-NakedButton") instead.

@SunderamDubey In Selenium 4 it does not work, it all changed please check your answer before reply.  u have to use find_element(By.ID,"id") etc.

@MuhammedSamedÖzmen Ya I was not sure, haven't used it from sometime that's why I wrote it as a comment.

It should be like that. If there is only one class then use find_element(By.CLASS_NAME," #what is class name"). However, button has 2 different class so u need to use CSS_SELECTOR instead CLASS_NAME. Finally fyi "class name" doesn't work in find_elements as an argument.
Button = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,".css-v84xw-NakedButton .eml2css7")

For more details you can take look on Selenium Doc.
